# what's the best method to detect lane lines using raspberry pi?

Tags: python, pi-4, computer-vision

i have a question about a project that im working on.  im making a lane keeping assistant on a self driving car (im using a toy battery car that a kid can ride on) which requires me to detect the lane lines using a camera on a raspberry pi 4. so my question is that what method of lane detection would you recommend me to use on this project? i was thinking that using some ML in python to train on some images to output the decision of where the car should go would be too overwhelming for the RPi and it's gonna take too long to get the decision  and the car would just go off the lane instead. is there other thing that i should pay attention to regarding the lane detection stuff?

Comment: Ah let me see. Everybody says TF is good.

Comment: @tlfong01, what does `tax free` have to do with the question? ... don't get me wrong, I also believe that it is good

Comment: @jsotola, sorry, I am using the Op's language. ML denotes Machine Learning, TF tensorFlow. Actually the OP's use of ML is a bit vague. He might mean using OpenGL with pattern recognition algorithms.

Comment: @tlfong01, lol ... i actually thought that you meant `time of flight` and i was trying to figure out how that would be used for detecting lane lines ... i just could not resist the tax free reference

Comment: @jsotola, Ah yes, I was talking to the OP, so I used acronyms to make it OP friendly. If I am making an answer for all readers, including newbies who would not guess what is ML, I would, before my answer, paraphrase the OP's question with acronyms followed by bracketed long form, eg TF (tensorFLOW). I would also list references to make sure the readers know which areas my answer falls in. Usually I would include YouTubes and images to help my broken 
English express better. The following YT is what I would start with my answer: / to continue, ...

Comment: "Lane detection and object detection with OpenCV & TensorFlow - 183,776 views 2018apr01", https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2VaJvNNp4k. Usually I grouped this forum's questions into (1) Please debug the following code segment for me, (2) Please google this problem for me, Often before me answering, I do google to make sure my knowledge is up to date. Usually I would watch and also including in my answer the most popular (1000+ likes) answer with a wider perspective and newbie friendly (eg, driverless car, lang detection, comp[uter vision, AI, Machine Learning, OpenCV, Tensor Flow etc).

Comment: This is another YT about image classification in real time, which is what the OP is asking: If Rpi tensorFlow fast enough to drive his battery toy car?
(2) TED Talk: How computers learn to recognize objects instantly, Joseph Redmon, 8 min, 866,361 views, 23k likes, 2017aug18
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cgxsv1riJhI